# MongoDb Morphia Write Concern

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm using Java thread processes, and i've some write/update issues using MongoDB 3.0 (not sharded) and Morphia. Here's how it works:

1) Thread A update some data in a document having a specific "_id" (through Morphia ODM)

2) After doing document.save(), Thread A send "_id" to Thread B

3) Thread B receive "_id", query MongoDB to retrieve the written document

Sometimes, thread B receive "_id", query MongoDB but doesn't get an updated version of the document (still old values).

I think it's a write concern problem. I've set up MongoDB client and Morphia datastore like this :

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress (host,port),
                                              credential);
    Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, datastoreName);

    // Setting up writeconcern
    WriteConcern wc=new WriteConcern(1,0,false,true);
    datastore.setDefaultWriteConcern(wc);
    mongoClient.setWriteConcern(wc);
```

Is there something i'm missing ? How to really wait the document to be updated in MongoDB by Morphia before sending the message to Thread B ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you'll want a majority write concern: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#MAJORITY
2. Have you configured the right read preference? `primary` or `primaryPreferred` is what you want, see http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html#primary--

PS: I think your WriteConcern creation is deprecated: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#WriteConcern-java.lang.String-int-boolean-boolean-

Comment: No, those settings are for replica sets

Comment: ok thanks. I only have 1 mongodb instance on 1 server. I've replaced deprecated WriteConcern wc=new WriteConcern(1,0,false,true); with WriteConcern.JOURNALED (but it's exactly the same according to the WriteConcern class definition)

Comment: with a single server this very odd. write concern 1 guarantees that your query has been applied in memory and should be served from there. are you sure this is not a threading issue / you're really waiting for the first query to be applied in memory?

Comment: Yes this is odd. I'm sure Thread A send the message to Thread B after doing a datastore.save(document); but i'm not sure that Morphia really hang my thread until the document is really "JOURNALED"